# Calculating number of data buckets used in hash tables

Tags: hashtable

I am studying Hash Tables and I have a doubt in which we have to calculate the number of data buckets used(primary and overflow).

It's a linear hash table with i = 3(number of bits used) and if the largest bucket address used(in bits) = '110' and there are 2 overflow buckets used.

What is the logic of calculating a hash table bucket count ?

Can you explain the formula or please provide some link related to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an interesting question about fundementals, please rephrase the question to an actual question, like, "What is the logic of caclulating a hash table bucket count"

Comment: done thank you for your kind advice.. its my first time here at stackoverflow.. i am still learning :D

Comment: Are you talking about total number of buckets inclusive of collisions which would be hashtable.size() or last used bucket let's say 15th bucket (filled) in case of hashtable of size 16(0 to 15)?

Comment: I am talking about total number of buckets inclusive of collisions which would be hashtable.size()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Implementation classes provided by Java then you can use hashtable.size() but if you still want to count it yourself then

```
Iterator i = hashTable.entrySet().iterator();
int count = 0;

    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        count++;
        i.next();
    }

System.out.println(count);
```

If you areusing your custom implementation then

```
private Entry<K,V>[] table;   //Array of Entry.
private int capacity= 16;  //Initial capacity of Hashmap
int count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
       if(table[i]!=null){
              Entry<K, V> entry=table[i];
              while(entry!=null){
                    count++;
                    entry=entry.next;
              }
       }
   }
Syso(count);
```

Here i haven't considered synchronization which is essential in case of hashtable.